# Как получить значения в не subscribe

Tags: angular4, rxjs

```
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

confirmPost:CreatePost[] = [];
unconfirmPost:CreatePost[] = [];


constructor(
private postService: PostService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.postService.getPosts()
  .subscribe((post: CreatePost[])=>{
    this.confirmPost = post.filter(p => p.confirm === true);
    this.unconfirmPost = post.filter(p => p.confirm === false);
     });
  }
}
```

Получаю массив постов из сервиса postService, дальше отфильтровую массив и хочу занести в переменние this.confirmPost и тд., чтоб передать в дочерный елемент . Но дела в том что в не подписке this.confirmPost равен пустому массиву.Как исправить?

Comment: никак, это асинхронный код :) и, к сожалению, вопросов один в один с твоим на stack overflow просто тьма, зачем дубликат создавать то? :)

Comment: Как мне тогда прокинуть массив?Получеться никак, надо тогда ето делать уже в самом компоненте , верно?

Comment: а что в твоем понимании "прокинуть" массив? куда прокинуть? массив-то у тебя доступен внутри "subscribe" блока, вот там его и используй, а шаблон автоматически апдейтнется

Comment: confirmPost мне надо прокинуть в дочерный елемент

Comment: в данный момент код - правильный и никаких велосипедов не нужно :)

Comment: PostComponent у мня состоит из 5 других компонентов, и мне нужен доступ к confirmPost в одно из елементов!

Comment: вот ты как "в одно ухо влетело, в другое вылетело"  я ж тебе сказал, что после того как функция внутри "subscribe" выполнится и `confirmPost` засеттится, то шаблон обновится и шаблоны твоих дочерних компонентов точно также обновятся